# tellg() returns -1 only for small files

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I ran across a peculiar issue. Let's say I'm reading a file like this:

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::string text;
in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
text.resize(in.tellg());
in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
in.read(&text[0], text.size());
```

The problem arises when the file contains less than 4 characters, i.e. `"ab"` or `"abc"`, but works in other cases as intended, i.e. `"abcd"` or larger.

Why is `tellg` returning `-1` for such a situation (ultimately causing my string to throw a `std::length_error`)?

**Additional info:**

I'm working with MSVC 15.5.3 (if not the latest, one of the more contemporary). Reproduced with GCC 5.1 as well.

This error doesn't occur with the equivalent C-style:

```
FILE* f = fopen("text.txt", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(f);
```

**EDIT:**

`failbit` is set right before the first call to `seekg`, meaning opening the file failed? Why would that be the case for a file of less than 3 bytes...

Comment: What are the values of `failbit` and `badbit` following the `-1` return?

Comment: Are you sure you're using C++11 ?

Comment: @paxdiablo failbit is set, badbit is not.

Comment: @SidS C++98 doesn't guarantee contiguous std::string storage, so the first code snippet would be UB.

Comment: There is also this:
C++98, istream::seekg: "If the eofbit flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets failbit and returns)."

Comment: Okay, that implies the sentry object couldn't be created. What is the value of `goodbit/badbit/eofbit/failbit` *before* the `tellg`? What was the return value from `seekg`? FWIW, I can't reproduce this problem in g++ 5.4.

Comment: @paxdiablo I edited the question with more info.  Only `failbit` is ever set. Any operation after that is then void I suppose.

Comment: If you can't open the file, it either doesn't exist or isn't in the current directory. The size of the file might just be a coincidence.

Comment: DeiDei, yes, that's correct, and we've now solved the issue as to why `tellg` is returning -1. Unfortunately the root cause as to why `failbit` is being set on open is still a mystery. My best answer to that is "stuffed if I know" :-) Maybe someone else can help out. For a quck check of pathing, try using the full name of the file in your code, something like `/path/to/file.txt`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not the case sadly. It only fails to open for small sizes. Double checked! (That is assuming it fails to open.)

Comment: I still think it's a current directory problem. Try using a full pathname.

Comment: Is `eofbit` set after the `ifstream` is opened?  Maybe it reads a few bytes when the file is opened, hitting eof, and seting `eofbit` and `failbit`?

Comment: running on windows? Run procmon and watch what io it does and what fails. On linux do strace

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I would see it as a rather serious bug if it said it was at EOF when it hadn't actually *read* anything. Even if it *did* read something to check the file out, that should not be made visible to the caller - it would have to be backed out.

Comment: This program, which creates and tests files from 1 to 26 bytes, works fine in Visual Studio 2017, 2015, and here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f892f2a47a45d305

Comment: One way to have failbit set before any operation on it is when you reuse a stream object. If the previous use of a stream sets failbit and you don't clear it before you close it and reopen the stream (even when opening a different file) the failbit is still set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few comments, it's clear that the `ifstream` constructor itself is failing in some way, as `failbit` is set even *before* the `seekg` call.

Since pretty much *all* I/O operation first construct a sentry object before proceeding, that will be why your operations are failing.

So I have a few suggestions.

First, use the *full* path name to your file just to ensure there's no possibility you're running it in a directory *other* than where the input file is.

Second, try the following *complete* program which works under g++ 5.4<sup>(a)</sup> to see if it exhibits the same problem (your code, while indicative, was not really complete).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("/full/path/to/file.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::cout << "after open, good=" << in.good() << ", bad=" << in.bad()
        << ", fail=" << in.fail() << ", eof=" << in.eof() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "seekg returns " << in.seekg(0, std::ios::end) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "after seek, good=" << in.good() << ", bad=" << in.bad()
        << ", fail=" << in.fail() << ", eof=" << in.eof() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "tellg returns " << in.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "after tell, good=" << in.good() << ", bad=" << in.bad()
        << ", fail=" << in.fail() << ", eof=" << in.eof() << std::endl;
}
```

Try this both with a two-byte and ten-byte file.

If none of that gives you any joy, Microsoft and/or GNU should be made aware of the issue. The former can be done [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), the latter [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

---

Just for completeness, the only *possibility* that originally came to my mind was that the file, although three bytes long, is invalid in some way. This depends on the actual content so, if it *is* just `abc`, you can safely ignore this.

What I was thinking is something along the lines of a Unicode file with two byte BOM and the first byte of a multi-byte Unicode code point (e.g., UTF-16), or the first three bytes of of UTF-8 four-byte code point.

However, that seems *incredibly* unlikely if you're opening it in binary mode, so you can probably safely ignore it.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For what it's worth, the *only* way I could get this to have `failbit` set after the open was to delete the file. Even using an empty file did not exhibit the problem you're describing.

Comment: One way to have failbit set before any operation on it is when you reuse a stream object. If the previous use of a stream sets failbit and you don't clear it before you close it and reopen the stream (even when opening a different file) the failbit is still set.